# Community detection in mobile social network

Tags: references, social-network

Can anyone guide me regarding any good survey papers and implementations of recently published papers on community detection in mobile social network.

I am willing to implement any existing algorithm and then R&D my own algorithm. I would be using ONE simulator for the purpose of community detection based on real data traces from a college campus.

Answer (score 5):

A short overview of community detection approaches is in [this blog post](http://digitalinterface.blogspot.it/2013/05/community-detection-in-graphs.html). It bases on a longer overview, being the standard reference:

- S. Fortunato, [Community detection in graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.physrep.2009.11.002), Physics Reports 486, 75 (2010), [arXiv:0906.0612](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0612).

Two nice algorithms working for big graphs are [Louvain](https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/) and [Infomap](http://www.mapequation.org/code.html), with the later (arguably) having stronger theoretical background.