# How to find out is the difference between two social networks based on their assortativity significant?

Tags: statistical-significance, networks, social-network

I've got two networks and I want to prove somehow that one of them is more homophilic not by chance.

Answer (score 1):

One standard way to go is calculating the [clustering coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient). If you want to go at larger scales than "neighbour of a neighbour" then you can compute the [modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_%28networks%29) given some community detection (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137613/6552)).

To show that it is not by chance, you need to construct some model for your network. 
It would be easier for the clustering coefficient (as it is number of triangles over maximal possible number of triangles). E.g. if you assume that for a given network there is a given probability to have a link between neighbour of a neighbour, then for a fixed linking you can get Bayesian estimate of this probability.